# pass a parameter from a views to a javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, parameter-passing

I have the next variable in my `main_controller.rb`:

```
def create:
   @token = "24vgd32"
end
```

in my `views/create.erb`, I wrote:

```
<%= javascript_tag do %>
   window.my_token = '<%= j @token %>';
<% end %>
```

by this way, I can use this variable in any of the JavaScript files that this page references.

but how can I use it in my `application.js`?

this is my `application.js`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  licensario.getLicense({
    wizardToken: my_token
  });
});
```

any help appreciated!

Comment: You can put this value in a hidden field and use that field's value in javascript.

Comment: how can I do that? window.my_token = '<%= j.hidden_field @token %>'; ? and what next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your create.html.erb use this

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :my_token, @token, :id => 'some_field_id' %>
```

replace the **some_field_id** and **my_token** with desired names.

In your javascript file

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  token = $('#some_field_id').val();
  //use your token for any other means.
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I see 3 ways :

- You can use erb in your js file, naming it `application.js.erb`. However, the data you want to pass must be available when the file is compiled, so this is probably not what you want to do;
- You can make a XHR request to your server to fetch the value you want;
- You can embed the value in the dom of your view. Some will suggest using a hidden field, I rather tend to use data attributes. For instance, `<body data-my-value="32">...`. You can retrieve it in your js by doing `$('body').data('my-value')`. Be careful to call this once the dom is loaded.

I tend to use the latter.

Answer (score 1):

`window.my_token` makes `my_token` a variable on the global scope; once it's been defined it **is** available to `application.js` as simply `my_token`.

Comment: `$(document).ready(` is going to prevent the enclosed code from running until the DOM loads. The DOM isn't going to finish loading when you have an inline `<script>` tag containing the `my_token` assignment until **after** `my_token` has a value. This means when the domready function finally runs, `my_token` will have a value set from the view.